# How to run program in cygwin using python script from windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cygwin, 64-bit

I want to run a program in cygwin through command using python script from windows level and pass parameters for stdin.
I read through many topics on stackoverflow already, but solutions which I have found don't work for me.
Here is code based on stack topics:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cygwin = Popen(['CYGWINPATH\\bash.exe', '-'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
cygwin.communicate(input="commandToRun")
```

This doesn't find proper command:

```
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: uname: command not found
('', None)
```

EDIT : Credit to matzeri for suggesting bash instead of mintty.
Example: I have a python script on windows desktop and after doubleclick I want to open program inside of cygwin and pass parameters for stdin.

Answer (score 2):

mintty is not a command shell, you should use bash instead.

```
$ cat prova.py
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cygwin = Popen(['bash'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
result=cygwin.communicate(input="uname -a")
print result
```

so you can have

```
$ ./prova.py
    ('CYGWIN_NT-6.1 GE-MATZERI-EU 2.5.2(0.297/5/3) 2016-06-23 14:29 x86_64 Cygwin\n', None)
```

Second example with a stand alone program

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cygwin = Popen(['lftp'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
result=cygwin.communicate(
input=" set dns:order inet inet6 \n\
open ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/cygwin/x86/release\n\
find lftp\n\
quit ")
print result[0]
```

and the output is

```
$ ./prova2.py
lftp/
lftp/lftp-4.6.5-1-src.tar.xz
lftp/lftp-4.6.5-1.tar.xz
lftp/lftp-4.7.2-1-src.tar.xz
lftp/lftp-4.7.2-1.tar.xz
lftp/lftp-debuginfo/
lftp/lftp-debuginfo/lftp-debuginfo-4.6.5-1.tar.xz
lftp/lftp-debuginfo/lftp-debuginfo-4.7.2-1.tar.xz
lftp/lftp-debuginfo/md5.sum
lftp/lftp-debuginfo/setup.hint
lftp/lftp-debuginfo/sha512.sum
lftp/md5.sum
lftp/setup.hint
lftp/sha512.sum
```

Comment: This is good answer if you run python script from cygwin level, not windows. Thank you for posting this :) !